# c# parser error message

Tags: c#, visual-studio

need help with how to correct this please

Server Error in '/pulse' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'pulsesite.MvcApplication'.

Source Error: Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="pulsesite.MvcApplication" Language="VB" %>

Source File: /pulse/global.asax Line: 1 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET

Version:4.0.30319.1

i know its just about changing the code but i'm not good with c# anyone know how?

Comment: I'm confused. You mention C# ("i'm not good with c#"), but the code is referencing VB ("<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="pulsesite.MvcApplication" Language="VB" %>"). Which one are you using?

Comment: is this a web forms application or MVC? if MVC, which version of MVC?

Comment: sorry fixed it now a rebuild seemed to work :)

Comment: @Sam, then either vote to delete your question, or provide an answer and accept it so that it gets removed from the questions queue.

Comment: and sorry for the previous typo im new to this as you can tell

Answer (score 1):

rebuild needed.